# How to create a type instance of class in haskell?

Tags: haskell, types, church-encoding

I'm a newbie in Haskell.

I'm looking if there's any way to create an instance of type of a class.

Is there any way to get this code working without using data or newtype?

```
type N = ∀n. (n -> n) -> n -> n

instance Printable N where
        print :: N -> IO ()
        read  :: String -> N
```

When I try to load the module in GHCi it tells me:

```
Illegal polymorphic or qualified type: N
In the instance declaration for ‘Printable N’
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use `newtype` ?

Comment: if I use newtype or data I need to write something like: `newtype N = N (n -> n) -> n -> n)` and then rewrite functions like `(+) (N a) (N b) = stuff` instead of `(+) = \a b -> stuff` without unboxing a or b.

Comment: Impredicativity is best to be avoided in current GHC. No way around that but to use `newtype` or `data`. (Also look up safe coercions, which make `newtype`s much simpler to handle in some cases).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you've written there looks a lot like a *class declaration*, not an instance. Perhaps you meant this?

```
class Printable n where
  print :: n -> IO ()
  read  :: String -> n
```

Note that the `n` has to be lowercase, because that's the *type variable* you're quantising the class over. If you actually want to define an instance, then you, well, *instantiate* `n` with `N`:

```
instance Printable N where
  print n = ...
  read str = ...
```

At this point the *type signatures* are all fixed (from the class definition) and what you need to write are the actual bindings of these functions, hence it must be `=`, not `::`.

Question is: why do you need your own class anyway? It's only going to cause name clashes with the standard functions `print` and `read` that are already in the prelude. What you actually should be doing is instantiate *those standard classes* with your `N` type, i.e.

```
instance Show N where
  show n = ...
instance Read N where
  readsPrec _ str = ...
```

That said, to get to the actual question you've asked: *no*, it is not possible to define *any* instances sensibly for a polymorphic type like `∀ n . (n->n) -> n->n`. How is the compiler supposed to distinguish this from more specific types like `(Int->Int) -> Int->Int`, or more general ones like `∀ n m . (n->m) -> n->m`? It's pretty hopeless. The *correct* thing to do is to just wrap it in a newtype; that hides the universal quantification and allows the compiler to properly distinguish `N` from other types.

Alternatively, you can just write *monomorphic functions* that accept/yield `N` directly:

```
showChurch :: N -> String
showChurch n = ...
readsPrecChurch :: Int -> ReadS N
readsPrecChurch _ str = ...
```

Actually the latter one is already too much for the type system: the `ReadS N` is short for

```
readsPrecChurch :: Int -> String -> [(∀ n . (n->n) -> n->n, String)]
```

universal quantification within a list? Uh oh. That's an impredicative type. GHC does have an `-XImpredicativeTypes` extension, but it doesn't really work.

Again, just avoid these problems by not openly using polymorphic types. There are a few great uses for Rank-N types (notably lenses), but most of the time they're completely overkill and unnecessary. There's certainly never a good reason to actually use church numerals like that.

```
newtype N = Church { getChurch :: ∀ n . (n->n) -> n->n }
```

will allow you to define arbitrary instances or functions without problem. And, practically speaking, simply doing

```
type N = Int
```

with all the standard instances that come for integers is of course just as good...

Comment: Sorry I explained badly my question but you still answered it correctly, thanks a lot!